# Separate opportunity views

Tags: opportunity, account, related-list

I have a situation in which User X currently supports both Latin America and our south region . Is there any way to have two separate opportunity views, one for each region. If that is not possible, would it be possible to  create a second SFDC account for X to use for his LATAM opportunities?

Comment: Are you trying to making it easier for User X to see just the opportunities that are in each of these two regions when looking at an Opportunity object List view instead of looking at 'All Opportunities' where the Opportunities in these regions would be commingled?

Comment: is region a field on the account or Opportunity?  if the former, you'll need a cross-object formula field on Opportunity that references `account.region__c` - then you can create custom List Views for User X - one where region=latam and one where region='South'

Comment: Yea I am just trying to make it easier for  user X The oppurtunity views in South and LATAM has to be seperated so that he can see them with differentiation based on location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this using a Custom Field and [custom List Views](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customviews.htm)

If your region is defined at the Opportunity level: you would add a field to the Opportunity object which contained your regions, and then on the Opportunity object you can create a new View and filter by the values which you want to see in the view.

The screenshot below contains an example of creating a new view to show Opportunities with a Region of 'LATAM'.

If the Region is defined on the parent Account, you would create a cross-object formula field on the Opportunity, let's say `Account_Region__c` which has a value of `Account.Region__c` as suggested by @crop1645 above, and then your List View filter on the `Opportunity` object would compare against the value of this `Account_Region__c` formula field.

[image]